# Get text after first occurrence of a Character

Tags: c#

I'm making a win form app in visual studio, and I need to get the text after a comma, or any character if possible, I've been using `line.Split(',').Last();`, however I believe this should return an array if you have more than one comma, and would break my code if the string line, were to have more than one comma, I would like to get all text after the first comma. Thanks.

PS: I want everything after the first occurrence, so after the first usage of the character, any other comma's in the string shouldn't matter.

Example: String line = a,b,a
If I use line.Split(',').Last(); it should return an array, but I want one string, I want it to return b,a

Comment: `line.SubString(line.IndexOf(","))`

Comment: Use `string.IndexOf` to get the position of the comma, then `string.Substring` to get everything after this position

Comment: Why can't you use line.Split(',')[1] ?

Comment: Can you please update your post to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can further help you?

Comment: @ShreekeshMurkar it is _line.Split(new char[] {','},2)[1];_ good point anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use:
line.SubString(line.IndexOf(","));

line : "abc,dfghi,jk,lmn"
return is : ",dfghi,jk,lmn";

if you don't want first comma
use
line.Substring(line.IndexOf(",")).Remove(0, 1);